# What is the best way to load millions of records to Datastax solr?

Tags: datastax

We need to load millions of records to Cassandra daily and make the data searchable. If we use sstableloader to load the records to Cassandra, will they get indexed for solr? Is solr api the only way to load the records?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can use any Cassandra client too, as well as sstableloader: what gets inserted into Cassandra is automatically indexed into Solr.

Comment: you need to define the replication to the solr ring in the keyspace definition for datastax to take care of it!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this Solr Datastax documentation

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/migration/migrationTOC.html